# Can I define C# 8 beta compatible indexers in C# 7?

Tags: c#

It seems, that they require `System.Index` and `System.Range`

I can't find any NuGet packages that would provide these, similar to `ValueTuple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target .NET Core 3 (currently in preview), which contains those types. That allows you to use those types in a C# 7.0 program. Just use them like regular types (`Range.Create(1, 10)`).

If you can't target .NET Core 3, then there isn't a good solution.

Comment: That seems weird. AFAIK, there's nothing special about these types, and they could have been supplied via an assembly. Why do they need a completely new runtime?

Comment: You can (the compiler will recognize those types if you define them), but they will not unify with the official implementation. So you can end up in situations where two libraries want to exchange ranges, but there are actually two Range types which are no considered identical.

Comment: Are there any plans to wrap them similarly to https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/ ? It seems concerning, that one has to switch to .NET Core 3.0 to make it work uniformly

Comment: The plan is to not have such a package. Consider filing a corefx issue to collect such feedback.